# Подскажите несколько несложных алгоритмов хэширования строк

Tags: java, алгоритм, pascal, хеширование, любой-язык

Опишите пару алгоритмов для хэширования строк. Если есть, то с кодом на java или pascal.

Comment: На мой взгляд минусы не справедливы. Вопрос вполне корректен и ясен. Человек желает знать несложные алгоритмы хэширования + реализация.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пожалуйста, открываем исходники класса `java.lang.String`, находим там метод `hashCode`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: А что интересно, так, встроено ли преобразование `31 * h` в `(h << 5) - h` в **javac** (*по крайней мере в Си (Ubuntu, gcc -O3,  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz) код со сдвигом в полтора с лишним раза быстрее*) или разработчики пакета предпочли сохранить  очевидность алгоритма.

Comment: Что за переменная hash?

Comment: в String она объявлена как private int hash;

Comment: @Ник, это кешированное значение хэша. Поскольку строки неизменяемые, его достаточно вычислить один раз и записать в переменную экземпляра, далее можно просто её всегда отдавать, не вычисляя каждый раз заново.

Comment: @iksuy там еще хитро сделано, поле не volatile, т.е. подразумевается гонка данных. Но чтобы не убивать перформанс, разработчики умышленно на это пошли, посчитав, что несколько вычислений функции менее затратнее чем расходы на волантильное поле.

Comment: @avp я вам наврал, hashcode для String не реализован в виде интризиков - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l581 Приведенный выше код выполняется как есть

Answer (score 3):

Когда еще в стандарте С++ не было `unordered_map`, в своей реализации достаточно успешно использовал CRC (конкретно тогда использовал CRC16).

У Гантерота в "Оптимизация программ на С++" описан следующий вариант:

```
struct hash_c_string {
    void hash_combine(size_t& seed, T const& v) {
        seed ^= v + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }

    std::size_t operator() (char const* p) const {
        size_t hash = 0;
        for (; *p; ++p)
            hash_combine(hash, *p);
        return hash;
    }
};
```

А вообще - надо **экспериментировать**, для конкретного набора может пройти кажущийся совершенно плохим хэш, ну, и наоборот...

**Вдогонку** - можно посмотреть такую вещь, как [GPERF](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) - хотя это и далеко не самый *несложный* хэш :)